Math contents does not align when subscripts are used

\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\widthBlank}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\blankAnswerMath}{m}
{%
    \setlength{\widthBlank}{\widthof{$#1$} + 2em}%
    \noindent%
    {\parbox{\widthBlank}{\mathstrut\centering\color{DodgerBlue3}{$#1$}}}\llap{\color{gray}\rule{\widthBlank}{0.4pt}}%
}

\usepackage{eqparbox}

\begin{document}

The quick
$\blankAnswerMath{x}$
brown fox

$x \blankAnswerMath{{x}^{\ast}}$

$\displaystyle a_{{x} \blankAnswerMath{{x}^{\ast}}}$

\end{document}

When defining a custom command for underlining contents with padding, the contents does not align with other subscripts. The size of the command contents does not adhere to the default size for the current contents.

Try \parbox[b]  (untested). By default parbox vcenters. So use b or t

The size is not the same as the surrounding contents because nothing specifies the math style of the \parbox contents, so it is always \textstyle. This can be fixed using \mathpalette. As to the vertical alignment, as pointed out by daleif in the comments you can just add [b] to the \parbox to make it aligned with the baseline.

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\widthBlank}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{eqparbox}

\newcommand*{\blankAnswerMathinner}[2]{%
    \setlength{\widthBlank}{\widthof{$#1#2$} + 2em}%
    \noindent%
    {\parbox[b]{\widthBlank}{\mathstrut\centering\color{DodgerBlue3}$#1#2$}}\llap{\color{gray}\rule{\widthBlank}{0.4pt}}%
}
\newcommand*{\blankAnswerMath}[1]{%
    \mathpalette\blankAnswerMathinner{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

The quick
$\blankAnswerMath{x}$
brown fox

$x \blankAnswerMath{{x}^{\ast}}$

$\displaystyle a_{{x} \blankAnswerMath{{x}^{\ast}}}$

\end{document}

